# Firebase.createUser failed: First argument must be a valid object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase

When I try to create a user I get the following error: **Error: Firebase.createUser failed: First argument must be a valid object.**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router', 'firebase']);

myapp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
    controller: 'home.controller'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('createUser', {
   url: '/createUser',
   templateUrl: 'templates/createUser.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('login', {
   url: '/login',
   templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
  });

}]);

myapp.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
//    $rootScope.$state = $state;
//    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
//    $state.transitionTo('home');
      //console.log("runnin'");
});

myapp.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://amber-inferno-5836.firebaseIO.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);


myapp.controller('app.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, auth) {
  $scope.login = {};
  $scope.createUser = function() {
    auth.$createUser($scope.user)
    .then(function(userData) {
      console.log("User " + userData.uid + " created successfully!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    });
  };
  $scope.login = function() {
    auth.$authWithPassword($scope.login).then(function(authData) {
      // $state.go('');
      // console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
  };
  $scope.logout = function() {
    auth.$unauth();
  };
  auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
      $scope.activeUser = authData;
      $scope.login = {};
      console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
    } else {
      $scope.activeUser = false;
      console.log("Logged out");
      $state.go('home');
    }
  });
}]);

myapp.controller('home.controller', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $scope.statename = $state.current.name;
  $scope.message = 'Welcome';
  console.log("home.controller initialized! current state: " + $scope.statename);
  // $state.go("home");
}]);
```

Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<div class="new-account-panel">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form ng-submit="createUser()">
      <input class="inputBox" type="text" name="email" id="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email" />
      <br>
      <input class="inputBox" type="password" name="Password" id="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" />
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Create User</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bloc Base Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="app.controller">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>B<span>loc</span>I<span>t</span>O<span>ff</span></h1>
      <h3>- Task Management Simplified -</h3>
    </header>
      <div class="login">
        <h4><a ui-sref="login" href="/login">Login</a></h4>
        <h4><a ui-sref="createUser" href="/createUser">Create new Account</a></h4>
        <h4 ng-if="activeUser"><a ng-click="logout()" href="#">Log Out</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div ui-view="welcome"></div>
      <div ui-view>

      </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm still quite new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I have checked, and logging in and out still functions as they should. I'm sure its something simple but I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Thanks.

Comment: There do you bind your `app.controller` to this view? I don't see it in the router configuration.

Comment: App controller is bound to the index.html that this is injected into. If it would help I can post the index.html file. Thanks.

Comment: This might help you out: https://github.com/sbolel/FirebasePatterns/tree/master/Examples/User_Management -- it's an example user management factory/service/module I put together.

Comment: The HTML would help if you post it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Just added the index.html, hope this helps.

Comment: Figured it out, I had to define ($scope.user) within the app.controller like so...'$scope.user = {
    email : '',
    password : ''
  }'

Comment: $scope.login is all over the place (an object and also a method).  Might want to change names.